# Android Studio won't update it says bin/studio64.exe.vmoptions and bin/studio.exe.vmoptions are ABSENT

Tags: android-studio

Pretty self descriptive.  Last time I messed with the vmoptions file it didn't exist until I opened it then it wrecked everything and I had to reinstall.  It seems that my android studio works great without the vmoptions and I'm scared to mess with them at this point but not being able to update is concerning me.
[image]